# Why isn't the body content shown in the response C openssl client?

Tags: c, https, openssl

I have this C client that talk to a simple flask webapp

```
    int res2 = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/cert.pem" ,NULL) ;
    if ( res2 != 1)
    {
        printf("[-] SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() failed to load certificate \n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(XXXX);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("webapp_ip");
    connect(soc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if (ssl == NULL)
    {
        printf("[-] SSL_new() failed to create ssl object \n");
        return -1;
    }
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, soc);
    SSL_connect(ssl);
    char *request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webapp_ip:XXXX\r\nUser-Agent: TOPG\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, request, strlen(request));
    char buf[8192] = {0};
    int received = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 8192);
    printf("Total received [%d] \n"  , received);
```

this code send a request to the webapp and reads the response, but when it outputs the response to it does not show the body contents

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.11.2
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2023 10:33:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 18
Connection: close
```

the flask webapp is a simple request inspector

```
from flask  import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    puts(colored.yellow(str(request.headers)))
    return "bingo_you_found_me"
```

the c client code should show the phrase "bingo_you_found_me" but it does not, the buffer used to read the response is big enough to hold the data of the response headers and the body contents

I tried changing the body contents and changing the response from text to json but it still does not show the body of the request

Comment: because you didn't keep reading until you got to the end of the body?

Comment: @user253751 you are actually right but why isn't it reading all of the response in the big buffer ?

Comment: it doesn't have to. Why should it? this is just how sockets work and you can't assume that it will. This needs to be drilled into students' heads the moment they learn about TCP